# Ignore Unexpected WhiteSpace when parsing Serial Data as JSON

Tags: javascript, json, serial-port

I am sending serial data from Arduino to P5JS as webSerial Strings.

I then want to parse this string as JSON in P5JS. This is fine and functions.
However, occasionally the string is incomplete when sent from Arduino to P5JS. When I console.log the data I can see it is broken across multiple lines. This does not happen in the Arduino Serial Monitor.

What this means is it is unable to be read as valid JSON when this occurs. I am trying to write an if statement to only parseJSON when it is a complete string beginning `[{"` and ending `}]`. However, this is not working.

Is there another method I can use to do any of the following

1. Stop the incoming data going across multiple lines
2. Create and exception for non valid JSON
3. Another method of seeing if the String matches `[{"` and `}]`

Here is the code .

```js
function serialRead(data) {
  incomingData = data;

  const withoutLineBreaks = incomingData.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, " "); // clean up 
  console.log(withoutLineBreaks);
  const first3 = withoutLineBreaks.substring(0, 3);
  console.log(first3);

  const last2 = withoutLineBreaks.substring(withoutLineBreaks.length-3);
  console.log(last2);

  //ignore incomplete or double serial strings. Total hack effort.
  if ((first3 === '[{"')&&(last2==='}]')) {
  //   console.log("yes")
  gestureInfo = JSON.parse(withoutLineBreaks);
  console.log(gestureInfo);
}
}
```

UPDATE EDIT:
I have now made sure my JSON is sent as one whole string rather than 3 strings so incoming data is

```
[{"gesture":"tap","probability":0.35,"winner":"circle"}]
```

However, the issue still remains that if P5 breaks this incoming string onto multiple lines when receiving it over serial it is no longer valid JSON. A hack at the moment is to check the length of the string to make sure it is likely complete JSON so for example.

```
if (incomingData.length>=58) {}
```

But this seems like an inefficient and not 100% fool proof method.

Comment: Please may you provide an example of incoming data?

Comment: Yes there are 3 incoming String 
`[{"gesture":"tap","p":0.36}]`
`[{"gesture":"circle","p":0.64}]`
`[{"winner":"circle"}]`
If each is on a separate line it works. But occasionally in P5 only it gets split across multiple lines despite in Arduino sending a new line and carriage return after each string on `Serial.print()`

Comment: You'll need to parse each line as JSON individually.

Comment: so if it breaks it up across multiple lines it is no longer valid JSON and looks like 
`[{"g`
or double messages `[{"gesture":"circle","p":0.64}] [{"winner":"circle"}]`

Comment: Are they not individual JSON?

Comment: It's not valid JSON even if they're on the same line or not. You cannot have multiple root elements. Each line seems to be valid JSON, but together they're not

Comment: so more like 
`[
{"gesture":"circle","p":0.64},{"gesture":"tap","p":0.36},{"winner":"circle"}
]`

Comment: It still often breaks as invalid though because it breaks up in the console.log/print
so ends up as broken strings
`[{` then new line
`gest` etc

Comment: How can i avoid this when it isn't printing as that from the Arduino side?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED:
this is now resolved using

```js
  try {
    const json = JSON.parse(incomingData);
    processData(json); //only process Data if valid JSON
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("invalid json");
  }
```

This is what I was initially looking for. A validation flag but as is the case it is often finding the correct language to search for the answer.